# how to add a # in cfoutput?

Tags: html, ajax, string, coldfusion

I have to render the following html tags from an ajax query. Issue is cfml treats any string prefixed with # as an identifier. So I'm getting an error.

```
 <cfoutput>
                <table style="display:none;" width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="43%" bgcolor="#649DCA"><strong>Class</strong></td>
                        <td width="20%" bgcolor="#649DCA"><strong>Site</strong></td>
                        <td width="47%" bgcolor="#649DCA"><strong>Date/Time</strong></td>
                    </tr>
  </cfoutput>
```

Comment: I am surprised you did not find anything searching, as it is a very common question.  First result in bing for [coldfusion # sign output](http://www.adobe.com/support/coldfusion/getting_started/using_poundsigns_quotat/using_poundsigns_quotat04.html)

Comment: yes didnt find. I looked in <cfoutput> doc too

Comment: I can only assume there is code you left out. The code you posted does not contain any ColdFusion variables, so there is no reason to wrap it in CFOUTPUT tags.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to double up your #'s.

```
<td width="43%" bgcolor="##649DCA"><strong>Class</strong></td>
```

Personally, I would probably just use CSS and style the table separately.